# When exporting to Latex from Org, how do I stop equations from breaking my paragraphs apart

Tags: org-export, latex

When working with mathematics in Latex, if I add a percent sign between my previous textb block and my \begin{equation} block, and another percentage sign between my \end{equation} block and my next text block, I can prevent the text block after the equation from being indented. Is there a way I can accomplish the same thing when writing my document in org-mode and exporting it to Latex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the second paragraph with \noindent, as in:

```
\begin{equation}
x^2
\end{equation}

\noindent Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula.  Donec posuere augue in quam.  Etiam vel tortor sodales tellus ultricies commodo.  Suspendisse potenti.  Aenean in sem ac leo mollis blandit.  Donec neque quam, dignissim in, mollis nec, sagittis eu, wisi.  Phasellus lacus.  Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.  Phasellus at dui in ligula mollis ultricies.  Integer placerat tristique nisl.  Praesent augue.  Fusce commodo.  Vestibulum convallis, lorem a tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit, vitae placerat urna tortor vitae lacus.  Nullam libero mauris, consequat quis, varius et, dictum id, arcu.  Mauris mollis tincidunt felis.  Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque.  Nulla facilisis, risus a rhoncus fermentum, tellus tellus lacinia purus, et dictum nunc justo sit amet elit.
```

Or use a latex block so you can put a % in it.

```
Aliquam erat volutpat.  Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna.  In id erat non orci commodo lobortis.  Proin neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget, lacus.  Sed diam.  Praesent fermentum tempor tellus.  Nullam tempus.  Mauris ac felis vel velit tristique imperdiet.  Donec at pede.  Etiam vel neque nec dui dignissim bibendum.  Vivamus id enim.  Phasellus neque orci, porta a, aliquet quis, semper a, massa.  Phasellus purus.  Pellentesque tristique imperdiet tortor.  Nam euismod tellus id erat.

#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\begin{equation}
x^2
\end{equation}
%
#+END_EXPORT
Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula.  Donec posuere augue in quam.  Etiam vel tortor sodales tellus ultricies commodo.  Suspendisse potenti.  Aenean in sem ac leo mollis blandit.  Donec neque quam, dignissim in, mollis nec, sagittis eu, wisi.  Phasellus lacus.  Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.  Phasellus at dui in ligula mollis ultricies.  Integer placerat tristique nisl.  Praesent augue.  Fusce commodo.  Vestibulum convallis, lorem a tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit, vitae placerat urna tortor vitae lacus.  Nullam libero mauris, consequat quis, varius et, dictum id, arcu.  Mauris mollis tincidunt felis.  Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque.  Nulla facilisis, risus a rhoncus fermentum, tellus tellus lacinia purus, et dictum nunc justo sit amet elit.
```

Or, you can add a latex line like this to get a % there.

```
Aliquam erat volutpat.  Nunc eleifend leo vitae magna.  In id erat non orci commodo lobortis.  Proin neque massa, cursus ut, gravida ut, lobortis eget, lacus.  Sed diam.  Praesent fermentum tempor tellus.  Nullam tempus.  Mauris ac felis vel velit tristique imperdiet.  Donec at pede.  Etiam vel neque nec dui dignissim bibendum.  Vivamus id enim.  Phasellus neque orci, porta a, aliquet quis, semper a, massa.  Phasellus purus.  Pellentesque tristique imperdiet tortor.  Nam euismod tellus id erat.

\begin{equation}
x^2
\end{equation}
#+latex: %
Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula.  Donec posuere augue in quam.  Etiam vel tortor sodales tellus ultricies commodo.  Suspendisse potenti.  Aenean in sem ac leo mollis blandit.  Donec neque quam, dignissim in, mollis nec, sagittis eu, wisi.  Phasellus lacus.  Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.  Phasellus at dui in ligula mollis ultricies.  Integer placerat tristique nisl.  Praesent augue.  Fusce commodo.  Vestibulum convallis, lorem a tempus semper, dui dui euismod elit, vitae placerat urna tortor vitae lacus.  Nullam libero mauris, consequat quis, varius et, dictum id, arcu.  Mauris mollis tincidunt felis.  Aliquam feugiat tellus ut neque.  Nulla facilisis, risus a rhoncus fermentum, tellus tellus lacinia purus, et dictum nunc justo sit amet elit.
```